# Data-table don't show my DataSource Array

Tags: angular-material, angular5, datasource, mat-table

I have a problem that I do not know how to solve it from my component I send an array of Resource so that another component reads it and injects it into a DataSource that is read by a mat-table. Consulted the documentation of Angular, I see that it is correct. I do not know if it's something in the html that does not allow me to see it. Can someone tell me the reason?

Thank you so much

my .ts

```
 @Input() resources : Resource [];

public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource <Resource> ();
public ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.resources)
        this.dataSource.data = this.resources
   }
```

my .html

```
<mat-table class="resources-table" #table [dataSource]="resources" matSort [@animateStagger]="{value:'50'}" fusePerfectScrollbar>

    <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="_id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let resource">
            <p class="text-truncate">{{resource._id}}</p>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{'RESOURCE.NAME' | translate}}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let resource">
            <p class="text-truncate">{{resource.name}}</p>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

`console.log(this.resources)` is img:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `DataSource` property of Mat-Table in which you assinging the data:

HTML code:

```
                                    \/ <-- Here
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="_id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element._id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

TS code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-sorting-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-sorting-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-sorting-example.html',
})
export class TableSortingExample implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['_id', 'name'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    var elements = [{ _id: 1, name: 'Paul Walker' },
    { _id: 2, name: 'Lisa' }];

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(elements); // Set dataSource  like this 
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; // and then assign sort
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6vs4cw-bz8tba)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but the variable that I send has a different format to elements. Can you tell me how I modify my variable to be equal to elements?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UyEe21gcDbhQwRKE_Jqfl3USp5mddfa3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So do you want to change variable format that means only two keys do you want?